# How expensive would a DELETE and INSERT be relative to multiple SELECTs and an UPDATE?

Tags: java, mysql

My question is a little vague at the moment since I'm not sure that I'm supposed to post any company code online or anything. But here goes.

Suppose I need to update a specific field in a MySQL database. In order to do this using my Java client program, I have to use multiple `SELECT` statements in order to check that the field should be updated, and then appropriately update it using the information that has been retrieved.

eg.

```
//created a Connection called con already...
PreparedStatement selectStatement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM myTable" /*+ etc*/); //example query only! I'm not actually going to use "SELECT * FROM myTable"!
//more selectStatements follow
PreparedStatement updateStatement = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE myTable SET field1 = ? WHERE id = ?");
ResultSet rs = selectStatement.executeQuery();
//more ResultSets from the other selectStatements
//process ResultSets and retrieve information that indicates wwhether an update must take place
if(conditionOccurred) { //Assuming we need to update
    updateStatement.setText(...);
    updateStatement.executeUpdate();
}
```

(I haven't included `try-catch`es in the code (sorry, I'm a bit lazy since this is just a contrived example) but I'd have to catch the potential `SQLException`s as well, I guess...)

What I'm wondering is: will it still be more "expensive", or costly in terms of speed if I delete the row and then insert a new row that contains all the updated information, given that I now need to use multiple select statements to check whether an update should occur? (memory is not such a big issue at the moment, though if something I've done has a massive flaw with regards to this I'd love to hear it!)

**TL; DR:** If I use multiple `SELECT` statements and then an `UPDATE` to some field(s), will it be more efficient to simply `DELETE` and then `INSERT` a new row?

Extra details: the table I'm working with at the moment has an auto-incremented ID, a VARCHAR field (the one to be updated, has a uniqueness constraint), 2 date fields and a CHAR(64) field. Not sure if it helps in answering the question, but I'll provide it anyway.

Please let me know if there are more details you'd need, and thank you in advance to anyone who might provide some insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fully answer your question we would need to see your SELECT statement, however if your UPDATE does not alter the primary key values I would assume UPDATE is more efficient. The reasoning behind this is that an index values would not have to be adjusted where in the case of the DELETE & INSERT the index would be.

As in most cases the only sure fire way to test this is by using both methods and bench marking the elapsed time.

Comment: Ah, okay. With regards to your comment about needing to benchmark, I had a sneaking suspicion that this was the case. I didn't think about the indexing issues you pointed out. I assume then that if I've placed a uniqueness constraint upon the `VARCHAR` field being updated, then this would be problematic for an `UPDATE`? I've added the information to my original post, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering your question based on the knowledge I acquired from my advanced database management course. I would say it would be very subjective as your concern is in terms of speed here and not the usage of memory.

When retrieval are done, in terms of your `Select` statements, your data are cached and when any necessary `Update` are required, you directly edit the fields in the cache. This save a read and write trip if you were performing the latter of `Delete` and `Insert`.

This would in my understanding, save you processing time in terms of millisecond for one single transaction, and if you look at a big picture, it will save you a lot when multiple transaction are performed. However, if your select statements involves too many queries dealing with a large size of data, it might turn out that your latter method is more efficient.

I believe with your additional inputs of your SQL statements, we would be able to give you a better and more accurate advise. :) I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I haven't had a huge exposure to advanced databases (the innards) of a database so your answer is really helpful. Again, thank you! As I stated earlier, since I'm not sure about posting code I'll have to refrain but given that (I think) I'm getting a much better idea on the feasibility of each method.